# Joeblogs / CookComputer.XmlRpc to log in to wordpress giving error: Proxy Authorization Required

Tags: wordpress, vb.net, proxy, xml-rpc, joeblogs

Here is my code:

```
        Dim wrapper As New WordPressWrapper("http://www.website.co.uk/xmlrpc.php", txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

    Dim lastname As String = wrapper.GetUserInfo.LastName.ToString
    Dim firstname As String = wrapper.GetUserInfo.FirstName.ToString
    If firstname.Count > 1 And lastname.Count > 1 Then
        'saves inputted username and passwords to settings
        My.Settings.Username = txtUsername.Text
        My.Settings.Password = txtPassword.Text
        MsgBox("Successfully logged in as " & firstname & " " & lastname)
        ControlPanel.LoggedInToSite = True
        Me.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Login Failed")
        ControlPanel.LoggedInToSite = False
    End If
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcServerException' occurred in CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll

Additional information: Proxy Authorization Required
```

I have no idea why this is happening, please help! Thanks